# Alternate electronegativity measures for exotic atoms?

Tags: theoretical-chemistry, electronegativity, exotic-atoms

[image: Text]

An [exotic atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_atom) is an otherwise normal atom in which one or more sub-atomic particles have been replaced by other particles of the same charge. For example, electrons may be replaced by other negatively charged particles such as muons (muonic atoms) or pions (pionic atoms).

On normal atom, [electronegativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronegativity), symbolized as χ, is the tendency for an atom of a given chemical element to attract shared electrons (or electron density) when forming a chemical bond.

---

So for an exotic atom, will there be a new term beside electronegativity?

Such as:

- Muonnegativity
- Taunegativity
- Antielectronpositivity (Postitronpositivity)
- Antimuonpositivity
- Antitaupositivity
- Any others?

---

For a chemical compound made from exotic atoms and normal atoms, there will not be just an electronegativity within the chemistry bonds. Could we called it leptonnegativity scale, matrix, vector, tensors, or whatever it might be to measure its tendency to form chemical bonds and also antileptonpositivity for its counterpart?

Does it makes sense?

Comment: I think the "electro" in electronegativity has to do with electric charge, and is not intended as a direct reference to the electron itself as a subatomic particle. Contrast with the complementary term *electropositivity*. Not to mention that these are just rough concepts anyway, and anyone seriously working with exotic atoms would certainly make use of all the machinery of quantum electrodynamics at their disposal to make any predictions.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto But we also have terms: Electron affinity and Electron configuration. If electronegativity has to do with electric charge. Will those terms also change into electric charge affinity and electric charge configuration?

Comment: Funnily enough, those two additional concepts you mention *are* in fact directly tied to electrons, and you *could* readily define, for example, muon affinity and muon configuration. Unfortunately, I can't exactly make a list of which ones work and which ones don't. You need to be aware of the subtle difference between electro/electric and electron/electronic.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto Yes I'm aware, electron is a concrete entity. It could exist independently of mind. One of entity that hides behind it that we can draw from it, is charge, an abstract entity. The status of an entity that has an abstraction of charge is called electric. It's just that, I wonder if electron or muon affinity and electron or muon configuration, could be unified into let's say, charged particle affinity and charged particle configuration.

Comment: I do not think there is any sense in which "charged particle affinity" and "charged particle configuration" is useful, other than simply being a list of the individual properties. For example, in normal matter, muon affinities are wildly greater than electron affinities, with typical energies being around 200 times larger (around 1 kiloelectron-volt, or dozens of megajoules per mole). With regards to configuration, muons populate muonic orbitals completely independently of electrons, which populate electronic orbitals.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto Now that makes sense, I'm satisfied. Thank you very much.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/80203/what-is-a-hydrogen-like-or-hydrogenic-atom https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/125171/how-do-molecules-with-muons-and-electrons-bond https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44802/alternative-to-a-proton